# Mendel's argument question?

Tags: logic

I know this is an inaccurate representation of Mendel's argument (for the existence of genes):

"P1. If there are genes and they obey rules L then experiment crosses in the pea plants should exhibit the 3:1 ratios.

P2. Experimental crosses in the pea plants exhibited the 3:1 ratios.

(C) Therefore, there are genes and they obey rules L."

However I am confused where it goes wrong. For example, for P1 and P2, I see that they make sense. However when it is all summed up together, should I clarify that there are genes in pea plants that obey the rules L?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is actually a fundamental and nuanced point of science.  It goes from "this looks like it might be a good way to think about things" to "this is how things are."  The way one thinks about that transition varies by time period.  Because of the way you are phrasing the question, I have a feeling the modern scientific approach is the most meaningful, so I will do it first.

**Modern Scientific Approach**

In this scenario, we're going to need to define a few more propositions to properly capture the entire process, step by step.  First, we are going to start with Pp, the "prevailing hypothesis."  This is the presumed answer, based on what people knew at the time.  It's also something we'll be overturning, so don't be surprised that you already know its false:

> Pp: "Because there are two parents for each offspring, the experiment crosses should always exhibit 1:1 ratios."

Let's presume Mendel was a modern scientist, perhaps a grad student.  His adviser had noticed that Pp just didn't feel right in a few interesting corner cases, so had Mendel do a quick screening test.  Sure enough, Pp felt off.  The proportions were off by a long shot.  In fact, it looked like a 3:1 ratio in some situations, not a 1:1 ratio that Pp claimed would be found.  Mendel then develops his new theory of genes (rules L, in your phrasing) which predicts a 3:1 ratio.  Now he needs to "prove" it.  To do so, he sets up an experiment and makes a hypothesis H1:

> H1: "This experiment should reveal that my model is correct, including its prediction of a 3:1 ratio"

Now, to follow the scientific method, he sets up a null hypothesis, H0, with the intent of rejecting it via statistics

> H0: The experimental results will *not* consistent with a 3:1 ratio plus some random noise due to experimental error.

Mendel then does the experiment, analyses the results, determines that H0 can be rejected because it's just too statistically unlikely that the results had anything but a 3:1 ratio.

Now, if enough others agree with the work (potentially running their own experiments), the model Mendel proposed becomes the accepted theory, overturning Pp, and prevailing at least until someone starts playing with multiple alleles and publishes their own work.

Now he goes about "falsifying" Pp, by demonstrating that his new [conflicting] theory, P1, fits the data cleanly while Pp looks less reasonable because it is a poor match to the data.  To "prove" P1 using the scientific method, he uses one final proposition, the null-hypothesis, P0: "Pea plant crossings do not operate near a 3:1 ratio with a random variance around that point."  If the data from his upcomming rejects this P0, then the only valid theory remaining is P1.

Now Mendel runs his experiement, and sees that P2 is true.  This allows him to reject P0, the null hypothesis, leaving only P1 (3:1 ratios) as potentially true.  He has also rejected Pp in the process, because Pp (1:1 ratios) is part of P0 (anything but 3:1)

**More intuitive**

Of course, all of the modern scientific approach involved statistics and falsification of hypotheses, and all sorts of things that are relatively new phrasings.  More traditionally, the process may be simpler.  The fact that Mendel's model does a good job of explaining the experimental results and the prevailing model does a very poor job of explaining them may be sufficient to argue that Mendel's new model should be considered "right," without all the formalism of null-hypotheses and other features of modern scientific methodology.

**More pedantic**

An alternative approach is to observe that the prevailing model does a poor job of predicting experimental results, scratch together a theory, and state "The results of pea plant crossings is well modeled using the model, Rules L."  At this point, no statement of ontological truth is made, just an empirical announcement that this model fits the data so far.  Over time, if no better model comes forth, people may elect to change the phrasing to "The model is true," not because any additional evidence had come forth, but simply because it is convenient to think that way.  This may be very unsatisfying mathematically, but linguistically it captures how ideas evolve, simplify, and are passed on to new generations.

Comment: That would not be the null-hypothesis here.  If we want confidence that the ratio is 3:1, our null hypothesis would be that it isn't.  But that does not mean it is necessarily known to be anything else.  The null hypothesis would be that after we factor out the ratio of 3:1 what is left does not become random variation.

Comment: What is really missing from this notion of the scientific method is the inductive or theoretical step that makes us guess 3:1 is the right approximation to begin with.  It is not the next logical guess, after 1:1, for a lot of people, or someone would have guessed it before Mendel.

Comment: @jobermark Good point.  I ended up bundling together the null hypothesis of the new theory and the falsification of the old theory into one step.  I think it captures the actual process (involving humans) rather well, but you are correct that I overstepped in calling it the null hypothesis.

Comment: Sorry to be picky.

Comment: In this case I agree with your critique.  I often try to handwave over some of the detailed bits of arguments to avoid confusing the reader.  In this case, I think I agree that I introduce more confusion than I resolve.

Comment: @jobermark I've substantially edited it.  I don't like the wording, so I think I need to clarify, but I wanted to see if that new wording is at least close enough to the correct usage of the null hypothesis to work with.

Comment: Sorry to continue being picky.  But now you are putting thoughts in Mendel's head that first existed with 'Student'.  I only articulated the detailed version of H_0 to show how complex it was, and how unlikely anyone might think that, before modern statistics.  Pressing science before the 20th century into Popper's mold really does not work.

Comment: @jobermark I reformatted and added a bit more.  I tried to clarify the issue of anachronistic thinking, and I also included other approaches (including something akin to my first post).  This may become quite the answer by the end of this!

Answer (score 2):

The argument has the structure "A => B" with "A = genes and Rule L" and "B = phenotype shows ratio 3:1".

The experiments validates proposition B. But it would be a failure to conclude A.

You only assumed that condition A is sufficient for B, but not necessary for B. Hence B could be explained by a different, possibly even unknown condition C.

Answer (score 0):

Scientific demonstrations are not wholly logical demonstrations as Wehler points out; so the argument doesn't quite take the form that you put it in: a *syllogistic*.

Another useful modification is the null hypothesis as already indicated Ammon; a further one is to modify the final sentence to say: not that 'there is' and 'they obey' but to say 'it is *plausible* that there is ... and that tgey obey'

This is already implied though by other answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You can never learn or prove a theory from an experiment, you can only test one.  Experiments can increase or reduce your doubt of a theory, but never converge on proof.

Mendel is an exceptionally good example of this.

Mendel obviously did a lot of work before his published experiment that led him to make the guess he made.  He was already convinced.

Nowadays, since we have statistics, we can do experiments in ways that will predict our parameters for us (regression/correlation) and tell us how confident to be about the theory being tested, although the world is still too random for us to trust that too much.

Even now, with this kind of help and support, it all remains probabilities.

But Mendel lacked both of these, he needed to directly guess the ratios, based on a theory he needed to derive from scratch.  And he needed to verify this to his own satisfaction, with no objective measure of how much to trust his work.

In fact, there is strong evidence that Mendel was so convinced that he discarded data to make his point more obvious.  He did the experiment over and over again until he got the results he wanted.

We know now that genes on plants fall at definite distances apart on the DNA, and that subtly changes this ratio, in a way that makes Mendel's actual data incredibly unlikely, indicating that his data is very carefully selected, to a degree that would now be considered lying.

So Mendel learned absolutely nothing from the specific experiment he published!  He was already certain, and if it threatened to increase doubt, he would have just done it over.